# C# WPF MVVM сменить страницу

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет, пишу приложение в рамках (MVVM) в котором будет несколько кнопок по нажатию на каждую из которых, в отведенную область (допустим во frame, или как-нибудь иначе) должна загружаться новая view, но VM ДОЛЖНА ОСТАВАТЬСЯ ПРЕЖНЕЙ, т.е мне нужно одни и те же данные, (которые хранятся в модели) отображать по разному, как это реализовать?

Comment: Просто во время создания View указать ей в качестве DataContext существующую VM.

Comment: А как именно создать view??

Comment: Ведь, если я меняю view через frame - не могу же я в VM обратится к нему и указать путь к файлу - это будет нарушение

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991440/frame-navigation-datacontext-not-inherited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у вас одна и та же VM, то ваш вопрос реально о смене View, а значит, решать проблему нужно на уровне View.

Положим представления одно на одно в грид, и будем переключать их видимость в зависимости от нажатия кнопок. Чтобы одна кнопка отжималась при нажатии другой, используем стандартный трюк с `ToggleButton`.

Пишем:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="15"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RedButton,
                                   Converter={StaticResource B2V}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="24"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="15"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=BlueButton,
                                   Converter={StaticResource B2V}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="24"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" x:Name="RedButton"
                         Margin="5,0" Width="100" IsChecked="True" Content="Красная"/>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" x:Name="BlueButton"
                         Margin="5,0" Width="100" Content="Синяя"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: выберите вашу таблетку]